# Why I can't solve this question using binomial distribution?

Tags: probability, combinations, binomial-distribution

A shipment of $8$ similar microcomputers to a retail outlet contains $3$ that are
defective. If a school makes a random purchase of $2$ of these computers, find
the probability distribution for the number of defectives. 
Let $x$ be a random variable whose values $x$ are the possible numbers of
defective computers purchased by the school. Then $x$ can be any of the
numbers $0,1$ and $2$.

Can I solve this question using binomial distribution?

Comment: The binomial distribution describes a sum of $n$ independent identically distributed binary random variables. What, in your case, are the $8$ random variables? Are they independent?

Comment: No you can not use binomial distribution here.  The reason why not is because binomial distribution requires that the events in question are independent.  Here, the events are clearly dependent.  The correct distribution to use is the hypergeometric distribution.

Comment: @JMoravitz   Can u explain why these events are considered as dependent? I dont understand

Comment: Each physical computer exists only once.  We are sampling *without replacement*.  Given that the "first" computer sent was defective, the probability that the second computer is also defective dropped to $\frac{2}{7}$.  On the other hand, given that the first computer sent was not defective, the probability that the second computer is defective raises to $\frac{3}{7}$.  For the events to have been independent, the probability should not have changed.  Here, the probability changes based on what previously occurred.

Comment: The second is less likely to be defective if the first is defective, since there would be fewer defective items left to select from

Comment: Note, however, that the **expected** number of failures is the same (linearity of expectation). To give an idea of the difference: with the hypergeometric distribution, $P(X=0)=10/28\simeq0.357, P(X=1)=15/28\simeq0.536, P(X=2)=3/28\simeq0.107$, while with the binomial distribution, $P(X=0)=25/64\simeq 0.391, P(X=1)=30/64\simeq0.469, P(X=2)=9/64\simeq 0.141$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the binomial distribution doesn't apply in this case.

While it's true the values of $X$ are $0,1$ and $2$ the probability of selecting a defective computer depends on what's already been selected. This breaks the assumption of constant probability for the selection event required for the binomial distribution. The selections are not $i.i.d.$ i.e they are not identical and independently distributed.

Before any selection, the probability of selecting a defective computer is $3/8$. Say you then select a defective computer, then there are 2 defectives left and 7 computers. The new probability of a defective is $2/7$.

Of course, you may get a non-defective first time. Then there are still 7 computers left, but now 3 defectives remaining. The probability of a defective on the next selection is then $3/7$.

So the probabilities change, depending on what's already happened, i.e. the events are not independent.